# Nix config outside of NixOS

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh, nix, nixos

So I’m trying to make a development environment that’s easily reproducible (staying away from `home-manager` currently to understand Nix better). After enough searching around I figured out how to make a few custom derivations, use `buildEnv` for package sets, and use `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix` to do overrides. I’m working now to setup `zsh` and `oh-my-zsh` which have a ton of configuration options, but the only documentation I can find seems to suggest adding them to `configuration.nix`, which is a NixOS option I can’t use.

Currently my `config.nix` code looks something like this:

```
let 
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in {
  allowUnfree = true;

  programs = {
      zsh = {
        enable = true;
        promptInit = "source ${pkgs.zsh-powerlevel9k}/share/zsh-powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k.zsh-theme";
        ohMyZsh = {
            enable = true;
            plugins = ["autojump"];
            theme = "powerlevel9k/powerlevel9k";
        };
      };
  };

  packageOverrides = pkgs: with pkgs; rec {
    all = buildEnv {
      name = "all";
      paths = with pkgs; [
        tmuxinator
        zsh
        oh-my-zsh
        autojump
        ...
      ];
    };
  };
}
```

My understanding so far is that within `~/.config/nixpkgs/config.nix`, there should be a single config set which contains things like the overrides function and corresponds to documentation examples of `config.programs.zsh.enable`, etc. However, nothing I write in that programs section affects or causes a different ouput of any of my programs.

What am I missing? How can I affect the configuration options listed here (https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/blob/master/nixos/modules/programs/zsh/zsh.nix)?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be trying to use home-manager's config without using home-manager itself. As you can see in the NixOS module you linked, this actually sets up `/etc/zshrc` etc, so it's not intended for use in a user-local config and won't do anything there. If you look at the [corresponding home-manager module](https://github.com/rycee/home-manager/blob/master/modules/programs/zsh.nix), you'll see that it basically reimplements the whole module for user-local purposes. So you won't get far with this approach without relying on home-manager.